# How can I run my program with many different arguments in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have a Java Application project in Eclipse and the executable receives parameters. The application then outputs a result value in a file. I want to, after running with many different parameters, compare these results.

If I could do something like this, like in a command prompt, it would be perfect:

```
run MyProgram --a hi --b 200
run MyProgram --a hello --b 333
...
run MyProgram --a something --b 10000
```

How can I do this with the Eclipse IDE?

If I can't do it by the IDE means, what would be the best way to manually do it (like with a .bat file)?

Comment: In run configuration you should have an option for program arguments (As a tab in LUNA)

Comment: But can I configure it to run, for example, with 100 different input parameters one after another automatically, or I would have to, put the first, then run, see the result, change to the second, run... and then goes; it would be impractiable for me if it's the latter.

Comment: You can set up multiple run configurations, IIRC, but I don't think you can run them all at once. Personally, if this is a requirement, I'd probably alter the code to optionally accept args from a file, e.g., one set of args per line or something similar.

Comment: Or you can run it from command line. The class files are right there on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's simple.
Click on Run -> Run Configurations
Click on the Arguments tab.
You want to type in all your input values into the Program arguments window, with spaces (blank characters) between each value.
Then just click Apply, followed by Run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to run configuration, Arguments tab -> in the  program arguments text box -> type space separated values to send arguments.

If you want to dynamically pass values on every launch and don't wanna open run configuration, then click on variables button and choose string_prompt. And provide variable name as follows -

```
${string_prompt: varName1}
${string_prompt: varName2}.
```

So you will be popped up a dialog asking you to enter the input values.

**Better approach**
 would be to put all your input values in a txt file, read the input file line by line and run your logic and compare the results. This would make your life easier.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use script to run your program several times with different parameters. Follow the below procedure to achieve this.

I have a java program which takes one input parameter. Below is the code

```
package org.stackoverflow;

    public class Testing {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String inputString = args[0];
            System.out.println("inputString:" + inputString);

        }

    }
```

I prepared one **.bat** file (TestingJavaProgramming.bat) to run this program again and again with different parameter and write the result into a .txt file after printing the result into console.

*TestingJavaProgramming.bat file content*

```
cd D:\All_POCs\WorkSpace\TestCoreJava\src
javac org\stackoverflow\Testing.java
java org.stackoverflow.Testing "This is 1st time testing">>result.txt
java org.stackoverflow.Testing "This is 2nd time testing">>result.txt
type result.txt
```

And the output after executing the batch file

```
D:\>TestingJavaProgramming.bat

D:\>cd D:\All_POCs\WorkSpace\TestCoreJava\src

D:\All_POCs\WorkSpace\TestCoreJava\src>javac org\stackoverflow\Testing.java

D:\All_POCs\WorkSpace\TestCoreJava\src>java org.stackoverflow.Testing "This is 1st time testing" 1>>result.txt

D:\All_POCs\WorkSpace\TestCoreJava\src>java org.stackoverflow.Testing "This is 2nd time testing" 1>>result.txt

D:\All_POCs\WorkSpace\TestCoreJava\src>type result.txt
inputString:This is 1st time testing
inputString:This is 2nd time testing
```

You can also see the output inside the result.txt file.Hope my hints will help you.